Alexa skill doesn't launch audio stream in EN-US
I have a simple lambda python code that loads an audio stream.  I have tested it numerous times in dev and live and it works in EN-AU, EN-CA, EN-IN, and EN-UK.  The only thing it does it EN-US is load my stations logo, says you are now listening......but the audio stream does not follow.  Anyone have any ideas what I am missing, overlooking, or lacking?  I think all the languages should work the same since I have sync locales on.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
